# Phantom iOS cannot simulate Solana Pay QR code

Tags: phantom, devnet, solana-pay

I have contacted Phantom support and was told to post here.

I'm trying to get Phantom iOS to read Solana Pay QR codes to approve transactions. Phantom reads the QR codes but says that it is unable to simulate and does not allow me to approve. I know the QR codes and transactions are fine because I'm able to use the same wallet in the Solflare app to read the QR codes and approve the transactions. We've also tested with the Android version of Phantom and it is able to read and approve the transactions.

The transactions are for devnet, I've double checked to make sure the wallet network is set to devnet. The iOS phantom version used is 22.08.08 and the Android version is 22.07.25.

I think it may have something to do with the most recent update to Phantom. Are there any known issues with the most recent Phantom iOS update? Or is there anything specific to Phantom iOS QR codes that I should be aware of?

Comment: Hey William, are you able to share the code for the transaction? or some pseudo code of what the transaction is

Comment: The transaction is for a custom program. We're using Anchor to build the transaction. The transaction is comprised of 3 separate instructions - each instruction has about 10 accounts listed. When the transaction is serialized the options for "verifySignatures" and "requireAllSignatures" are both false. I can't share the code, but hopefully this info is helpful.

Comment: The same thing is now happening on Android with the newest version of Phantom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be an issue with the most recent update to Phantom iOS. According to the Phantom Developer Discord it should be resolved soon. I'm using Solflare to test while I wait for Phantom to fix the issue.